# can a ceiling fan with a light be controlled separately and having the light on a 3 way switch and have 2 dimmers and 1 switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

New home, walls open, can a ceiling fan with a light be controlled separately and having the light on a 3 way switch with 1 on a dimmer and the fan with a speed control (dimmer) if so how?

Thanks

Yves

Comment: The possible configurations are all over the map.  Some fans can only work with the special speed control sold with the fan, while others can work with controls from your neighborhood Quickie Mart.

Comment: Do you have a specific fan that your heart is set on, or are you still in the market for fans?

Answer (score 1):

Most ceiling fans with lights have the ability control the fan and light separately.  That would require two switched hots (black wires, or black+red in a 3 conductor cable) running from two switches to the fan.

The light (or the fan) can be wired to be controlled with 3 way switches.  The fan light, like any other light on a 3-way circuit, can use a dimmer, but only at one of the switch locations, I think.  Of course, the light in the ceiling fan would have to be compatible with the chosen dimmer.

I do not know if the fan would work with a dimmer control.  A lot depends on the fan.

Did you consider a fan/light combo with a remote control that would allow you to control the fan & light separately?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run a minimum of 14X3 W/G to the box where the fan control and light switch are. Check your fan instructions to be sure you do not need more. Generally 1 conductor for fan, 1 conductor for light, White is neutral (in usa), and earth ground. The box that has the needs power feed, that can be used for the fan and light. The additional switches you need to run 14x3 W/G.